# JTable column width to increase / decrease depending upon data length

Tags: swing, jtable

I have embedded a JTable within a scroll pane object. JTable is going to have 8 columns and all these 8 columns are going to contain string values. Functionality to be achieved is as follows:

1. User will select a file from his desktop
2. Code should read the given file and populate the data inside the file into the 8 columns of the JTable using a specific logic. This means, we do not know the standard width of the column in the JTable. Depending upon the file selected, data will vary and hence the column width of JTable.

My intention is that, if the data is long, code should elongate the column width automatically to show the entire text so that that user has no additional task to drag the column for seeing the entire text. And this should happen for each column in JTable. How can this be achieved in a JTable

P.S: I have enabled horizontal scroll bar for the scroll pane always so that even the column width elongates, user can see the table contents by moving the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

> code should elongate the column width automatically to show the entire text

Check out the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/). It shows how you can:

1. Use the table renderer to determines the size of each column
2. Or, use the supplied code to do this for you automatically.